# Где посмотреть все коды ошибок при регистрации?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

У меня поставленная регистрация:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email, Name=Input.Name,
                Surname = Input.Surname, ImgSrc = "/images/ava/ava15.png", Rang="Тень" };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(error.Code, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
```

Где я могу посмотреть коды ошибок при регистрации, которые заполняются в result.Errors? и как я могу изменить текст кода ошибок??

Comment: ну наверное внутри метода `_userManager.CreateAsync` ?

Comment: если вам чисто для фронта изменить текст надо, то может проще в foreach блоке вместо error.Description добавлять свой текст? определить switchcase для разных кодов ошибок

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov, Я так и думал. Но просто нужен в любом случаи список кодов (ключей), чтобы правильно заменять.

Comment: @chilo5432 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961648/how-to-localize-asp-net-identity-username-and-password-error-messages в ответах посмотрите

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov, спасибо!